# Java client socket using writeBytes

Tags: java, sockets

I'm reading a string from a buffer and writing it to a server. The problem I'm having is that the string never gets received by the server when I leave the socket open and write in a loop. 
When I use this:

```
    try {       
        Socket send = new Socket("localhost", 1490);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(send.getOutputStream());
        String message = null;
        while ((message = buffer.get()) != null){
            out.writeBytes(message);
        }
        out.close();
        send.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the server doesn't receive the string, but when I do this it works properly:

```
    try {       

        String message = null;
        while ((message = buffer.get()) != null){
            Socket send = new Socket("localhost", 1490);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(send.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeBytes(message);
            out.close();
            send.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Obviously I don't want to keep opening and closing the socket, though. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush your socket every time you want to send a data packet. 
Closing a socket forces an automatic flush and that explains why your data is getting sent on socket close.

Answer (score 0):

The data is not being written to the socket even when you close it? (in your first snippet that is)

Also, have you tried to use the *flush* method? You can read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#flush() and your code will look like:

```
try {       
    Socket send = new Socket("localhost", 1490);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(send.getOutputStream());
    String message = null;
    while ((message = buffer.get()) != null){
        out.writeBytes(message);
        out.flush();
    }
    out.close();
    send.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did try flush and I still have the same problem. The buffer always has strings, so I don't think the socket actually closes. But why are my message still not received?

Answer (score 0):

Let me make a guess.

Does the `buffer.get()` method block?  If so, then the problem is that `out.writeBytes(message)` does not guarantee that the entire byte representation to be pushed to the server.  Instead. there is a good chance that your client has buffered bytes waiting to be flushed through to the server.

If this is what is going on, then calling flush after each call to `writeBytes` will fix the problem.

But if the `buffer.get()` method doesn't block, then calling flush won't make any difference.  In fact, it will just increase the network traffic.  So adding the flush "just in case" is a bad idea.

---

Another possibility is that there is something wrong with the server-side code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, buffer.get() does block, but I did try flushing the buffer after each call to writeBytes and I still have the same problem. Any other ideas?