# java socket input streams

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a simple Client-Server Chat Application with client login. I've been on the web for days now searching for answers regarding the problem I'm currently encountering. I've tried all suggestions and "solutions"but I still can't get it to run properly.

The problem is with streams. If I close the Client output stream after sending a string to the server, the Server successfully reads the string. But then the server couldn't send back a response because the socket had been closed. If I don't close Client output stream, Server couldn't read any data sent by client. I've tried fiddling my code but to no avail.

Here is my Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

public static BufferedReader bf;
public static PrintWriter pw;
public static Socket s;
public static ClientLogin login = new ClientLogin();
public String me;

public static boolean connect(String ip, int port){
    try {
        s = new Socket(ip, port);
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        new ServerListener().start();

    }catch (ConnectException ce){
        return false;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void send(String msg){
    try{
        if(msg.length()>0){
            pw.write(msg);
            System.out.println("client message sent.. " + msg);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in client sender: " + e);
    }
}
}

class ServerListener extends Thread{

@Override
public void run(){

    String res = "";
    String input;
    try{
        System.out.println("client listening....");
        input = Client.bf.readLine();
        System.out.println(input);

        if(input.startsWith("LOGIN")){
            ClientLogin cl = new ClientLogin();
            cl.login(input);
        }else{
            ClientLogin.errorLabel.setText(input);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println("Error in Client listener: " + e); e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Server code:

```
package server;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ChatServer {
    public static final LinkedList<Socket> sockets = new LinkedList<>();
    private static Dbdriver db;
    private static int users;
    static clientThread cl = new clientThread();
    public static InetAddress ia;

public ChatServer(){
    db = new Dbdriver(); //database connection
    db.getClass();
    try{
        users = db.countUsers();
    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}

//START SERVER
public static void startServer(){
    clientThread s = new clientThread();
    s.start();
}

public static void stopServer(){
    try {
        synchronized(ChatServer.sockets){
            for(Socket ss:sockets){
                if(ss.isConnected()){
                    MessengerEngine.pw.close();
                    ss.close();
                }
            }
            sockets.clear();
        }
        cl.theServer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace(); }
}

}

class clientThread extends Thread {

public static ServerSocket theServer;

@Override
public void run() {
    int port = 8888;
    try{
        theServer = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true){
            MessengerEngine engine = new MessengerEngine(theServer.accept());
            engine.start();         
        }
    }catch(SocketException se){
    }catch(Exception e){ 
    }
}
}

class MessengerEngine extends Thread{

public static Dbdriver theDriver;
private Socket theSocket;
    private BufferedReader bf;
    private PrintWriter pw;

    public String ipadd;

public MessengerEngine(Socket s){
    theSocket = s;
    synchronized(ChatServer.sockets){
        ChatServer.sockets.add(theSocket);
    }

try{
        bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theSocket.getInputStream()));
        pw = new PrintWriter(theSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        ipadd = s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        AdminServer.serverLog.setText(AdminServer.serverLog.getText() + ipadd +" has connected." +"\n");
}catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Socket.accept error");
}
}

@Override
public void run(){

    String res = ""; //server response

        try{
            String input = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("String from client: " + input);
            String[] inputs= input.split("-");

            if(input.startsWith("LOGIN")){ //LOGIN - "LOGIN-name-pass-ip"
                Dbdriver db = new Dbdriver();
                res = db.userLogin(inputs[1], inputs[2], inputs[3]);
                System.out.println("Client logging in sent: " + inputs[1] + ", " + inputs[2] +", " + inputs[3]);
                send(res);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
}

public void send(String msg){
    System.out.println("Server trying to send: "+ msg);
    pw.write(msg);
    System.out.println("server sent message..");
}
}
```

All data from client are from text fields (username,password). I wanted the server to verify client login by checking from the database. Gathering from textfields and verifying login works perfectly. My only problem is the client input stream.. I think. Help a noob programming student? Please.

thrown exception by server:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at server.MessengerEngine.run(ChatServer.java:102)
```

ChatServer.java:102 >> String input = bf.readLine();

Comment: You don't need to create a new DataOutputStream just to close it.  But you must check the result of every readLine() for null, and if so close the socket and exit the thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java client socket using writeBytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341898/java-client-socket-using-writebytes)

Comment: @EJP noted sir. I make sure sent data aren't null.

Comment: @Brian Roach thanks for the link. But it didn't help either :c might as well give up on this little adventure of mine

Comment: @andreianna Perhaps starting with the [Oracle tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) would be a better place to start.

Comment: @BrianRoach I actually did base my earlier trials from java tutorials. But i don't know why its not working for me this time.. hmm.. oh well, just proves women aren't logical thinkers.

Comment: @andreianna No, I  think it proves you're just in a bit over your head for your current level is all. Your code, quite frankly, is very hard to even figure out what it's supposed to be doing with all the static variables and methods. You also shouldn't be extending Thread; it's only in rare cases that you do.

Answer (score -1):

You shall not close the streams until your communication is completed. It will always result in closing the socket as well. What you need to do is to use `dos.flush()` after writing something to data output stream to enable server get the information and close dos only after you completed your communication.

Comment: That's where i get confused actually. I tried flush()ing after writing to output stream, but then the server doesn't read the data. It just waits. :( Am I making any sense? :(

Comment: you are using readLine method on dis which is deprecated. if you are dealing with plain text you should use reader/writers. for example replacing dos with a print writer and din with a buffered reader will help

Comment: Oh. I'll do that now. :) Thanks!

Comment: Server listener is throwing the exception java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

Comment: need to see stack trace

Comment: Please update the code as well in order to trace the problem in code

Comment: From a client login jframe. Client pc = new Client(); pc.send(clientInput);
clientInput = name + password + ip
name and password are from textfields

Comment: where are you calling connect() method ?

Comment: from another jframe that lets user provide parameters ipAddress and port and connect to server. if the the connection is successful, user is then allowed to login to the chat app. Is this what's making the code not work?

Comment: It seems connection between client and server gets dropped after client sends message to the server. are you doing something after calling ps.send() ?

Comment: Well, the clientLogin would have to wait for a response from the Client.java.. a response that's originally from the server - the verification of login. `cl.login(input);`. `login()` method then decides what action to perform depending on the response sent

Comment: hi sir @sanjeev, i've solved the problem! :) Thank you though for patiently going thru my messy code.

Comment: On printwriter, i originally used `write()`. Then changed it to `println()` so server "detects" new line character :)

Comment: 'Connection reset' does not indicate a premature close by this end, and doesn't indicate lack of a `flush()` either, and he isn't using a `DataOutputStream` to send anything. Answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP if you will read all the comments then you will get to know that earlier he started using DataOutputStream and after my comment only OP changed it to reader.